# 3d Object as SceneSwitcher in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm programming a mobile game for a school project and I need help. I want to switch a scene when I'm clicking on a 3d object. I know how to do it with mouse input, but with touch input, I have no clue. I tried it a lot, but I didn't find a solution. Can anyone help me or send me the link to a tutorial?

[image: a scene in Unity]

[image: code in visual studio]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow (SO), before anything I recommend you take the [tour]. Afterwards, please [edit] your question to include attempts you've made and *why* they didn't work as properly formatted markdown ([images are bad](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)). As it stands right now, you're question is likely to get downvotes and close votes because it isn't obvious that you've made attempts at solving the problem (more on this topic [here](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/))

Comment: That being said, use [`Input.GetTouch`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html) and then do the same as your mouse code, just using the position of the touch input instead of the mouse input

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Input.GetTouch** to get touch information on the touch screen and then use **RaycastHit** to determine the selected object

**1. Get touch informaton**

```
Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
if (touch.tapCount == 1)
{
    if (GetObjectTouchByTag(touch.position) != null)
        SceneManager.LoadScene("SampleScene"); // switch scene with name SampleScene
    // ...
}
```

**2. Get 3D GameObject with RaycastHit**

```
// Raycast object by with tag
public GameObject GetObjectTouchByTag(Vector3 position)
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(position);
    RaycastHit[] raycastHits;
    raycastHits = Physics.RaycastAll(ray);
    foreach (RaycastHit hit in raycastHits)
    {
       if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "SampleObject")
       {
          return hit.collider.gameObject;
       }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Hope it can help you!